# MYSQL: get latest msg from each user

Tags: mysql

Hello i have a table users, which has the primary Key 'user_id' and a table messages which has the columns 'msg_id'(primary), 'msg_from', 'msg_to', 'msg_date', 'msg_text'. the columns msg_from and msg_to are filled with user_id's.

What i want is for a specific user(say user_id=1) to get a table with all users who had msgs with him and for each user the newest msg.

So the result should have the columns

```
 'id'(of the partner), 
 'msg_from', 
 'msg_to', 
 'msg_date', 
 'msg_text'
```

and each user occurs at most once. In Addition i want the table to be sorted by the column 'msg_date'

I know i can get the first column with

```
SELECT msg_from as id FROM messages WHERE msg_to=1 
UNION 
SELECT msg_to as id FROM messages WHERE msg_from=1
```

how can i add the latest msg?

Comment: I'd expect a WHERE clause that used the newest timestamp as criterion.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your description is really confused, and if I accept the literal semantics then the utility of the service will be grossly limited (it won't work as a messaging service)

Comment: if `msg_from` and  `msg_to` are id what you want the id of the partner?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT T.*,
               @rn := IF(@partner_id = partner_id
                         @rn + 1,
                         if(@partner_id := partner_id,1,1)
                        ) as rn
        FROM (
                SELECT  CASE WHEN `msg_from` = @userID THEN msg_to
                             WHEN `msg_to`   = @userID THEN msg_from
                        END as `partner_id`,
                        `msg_from`,
                        `msg_to`,
                        `msg_date`, 
                        `msg_text`
                FROM messages 
                WHERE @userID IN (`msg_from`, `msg_to`)
            ) T
        CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @partner_id := 0, @rn := 0, @userID := 1) as var
        ORDER BY `partner_id`, `msg_date` DESC
    ) T
WHERE T.rn = 1
```